# How to find the joint probability function where one of your parameters is a random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, density-function

Here is the question that I am trying to do.

The number of defects per yard $Y$ for a certain fabric is known to have a Poisson distribution with parameter $x\,$ (i.e. $f(Y|X = x)$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter x$)$. However, $x$ itself is a random variable with probability density function given by

$f(x) = e^{-x},\ x\ge 0$

and $\,f(x)$ is equal to $0$ everywhere else.

Find the joint probability function for $X$ and $Y$.

So what I was thinking you know that you want a function of $f(x,y)$. Since they tell you that it follows a Poisson distribution you would need a $\lambda$ and a $k$ value where the $\lambda$ is your average number of events per interval and $k$ is the number of events that occur. The way the question is worded $\lambda$=y and $k$=$x$.

$$P(k) = \frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\frac{y^{x}e^{-y}}{x!}=f(x,y)$$

So what I think is that $f(x,y)$ is the joint probability function since $x$ and $y$ are variables and not constants. What I was wondering is whether this is right or not? I'm a bit unsure because I'm not why they gave us the information that $f(Y|X = x)$. Did I have the correct approach or not? If not can I know what is wrong with my answer and how to correctly do this problem?

Comment: Hint : f(x,y)=f(y|x)*f(x)

Comment: Just wondering how would you know what $f(x|y)$ is?

Comment: Another thing I don't think you are given the marginal density function for x because the question didn't tell you that it was $f(x)$ was the marginal density function. It said it was the probability density function right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a conditional probability mass/density function can be written as follows:

$ f_Y(y|X=x) = \frac{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}{f_X(x)} $

You can solve for $ f_{Y,X}(y,x) $ to get:

$ f_{Y,X}(y,x) = f_Y(y|X=x) \times f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-x}y^x}{y!} \times e^{-x} = \frac{e^{-2x}y^x}{y!} $

Comment: Just wondering how do you figure out what $f_{y}(y|X=x)$ and $f_{x}(x)$ are?

Comment: I'm not sure if they give you that information in that question. If they do it would be really helpful if you could just let me know what those functions are?

Comment: @ShahKamal You are told that Y|X has a poisson distribution with parameter X, and the distribution of X is given by the exponential density function.

Comment: @ShahKamal This means that $ f_X(x) = e^{-x} $ and $ f_Y(y|X=x) = \frac{e^{-x}x^{y}}{y!} $

Comment: Just one more thing. In the question they say that the number of defect yards is equal to $Y$. I was wondering why would that correspond to $Y$ being equal to $\lambda$

Comment: @ShahKamal In the given Poisson distribution, $ x $ is $ \lambda $. Recall the probability mass function of a poisson distribution with parameter $ \lambda $: $ f_Y(Y=y) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}{\lambda}^y}{y!} $. You just replace $ \lambda $ by $ x $.